# How to get if current time is in work schedule

Tags: php

I'm building a simple system where there will be information what person and when they came to the office/factory and when they leave.

For example: Office days is Monday-Friday, factory schedule is 4 working days (2 days and 2 nights) and 4 free days.

I can't figure out how to calculate if the current datetime for the selected user is his working time or free time by assigned schedule.

Comment: there's 7 days in  a week how do you get 8 days?

Comment: You'll have to have a start time and calculate from that.  And then, vacations will screw that up, so you'll have to figure out how to handle that as well.  What do you have so far ... just the assignment?